# How to pass parameter to onOpen() function using SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: java, android

I'm  trying to create a to do list. For it, I need to store the user's tasks in a database. For that I choose to use SQLiteOpenHelper.

I proceed in this way:

1. get user input
2. Create a database using getWritableDatabase() + onCreate() function
3. Store user's input inside database -----> Don't know to do that.

   ```
   String task = String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());
   DatabaseHandler access = new DatabaseHandler(getApplication());
   access.getWritableDatabase();
   ```

Creation of the database (The function is @Override but can't formated it properly)

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         Log.d(TAG, "===Inside onCreate from DatabaseHandler===");
         String database_table = "CREATE TABLE task(ID INT NOT NULL, TASK CHAR(25), STATE CHAR(25))";
         db.execSQL(database_table);
     }
}
```

As you can see, I get the user's input using .getText() function.
Then I launche the onCreate() function using .getWritableDatabase()
And finally, the onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) is automatically call when the database is open. However I can't modify the prototype of the function and even if I could, I don't how can I pass argument to it. (assuming it's possible).

So I would like to know how can I pass argument to onOpen() function for add user's input to my database ?

EDIT:

My original question was to know how could I pass argument to onCreate() function. But I realize that I wanted to pass to onOpen() function instead of onCreate().

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> So I would like to know how can I pass argument to onCreate() function for add user's input to my database ?

You don't. You use the `SQLiteDatabase` returned by `getWritableDatabase()` to add your user input to the database.

Also, please do database I/O on a background thread; your current code is doing this on the main application thread, freezing your UI while that I/O is going on.

Both of these topics are covered in any decent book or course on Android app development.

Comment: Hello @CommonsWare, thank you for you fast answer. However I made a mistake while writing my post. Indeed, I asked for a way to pass parameter to onCreate. But realize that I wanted to pass argument to onOpen() function instead of onCreate function. I edited my original post. So how can I pass argument to onOpen() function ? Because even if I have to use SQLiteDatabase returned by getWritableDatase(), can I find a way to pass argument to onOpen() ? Or have I to add user's input directly from the function where I got the user's input ? Thanks

Comment: @S7_0: "So how can I pass argument to onOpen() function ?" -- you can't. "Or have I to add user's input directly from the function where I got the user's input ? " -- correct. After all, what happens when the user wants to change the data? Your database is already open. Again, this is covered in books, courses, [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass user input to `onOpen`. You add it to the table in the database that you created in `onCreate`.  You would then use:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues()
values.put(COLUMN_TASK, task);
// Add any more columns here

access.getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#WriteDbRow) for more details